# Execution failed for task ':sound_stream:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, github-issues

Execution failed for task ':sound_stream:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

What went wrong???

I had an old project and I upgrade  all packages and dependencies and gradle version and I had that issues